# Spring hibernate not updating the entity

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, quartz-scheduler

I have a Spring/JPA/Hibernate app and there is a piece of code which is called every minute by a quartz job to send out some notifications.

```
@Transactional
public void sendNotifications(){
    Set<MyEntity> entitySet = getDAO().findEntitiesToNotify();
    for (MyEntity e : entitySet) {
        sendEntityNotificationEmail(e);
        e.setNotification(true);
        this.merge(e);
    }
     return false;
 }
```

This works fine most of the time. The key phrase being "most of the time", because at times, this transaction does not update the database, so the notification email is sent every minute until I manually go and kill the quartz job or update the database. There is no error in the logs, nor is the database being updated. Does anyone have any idea on what could the issue be? Or any way I can debug this issue. Is there some race condition happening because this method is called every single minute, so a new thread is calling the same task again while another one is processing it, and therefore the change is not persisted?

Comment: how can void method return boolean? seems you forgot some details while posting question.

Comment: why merge and not saveorupdate?

Comment: why merge and not persist? eventualy use "flush()", write more code

Answer (score 0):

it could be better to send notifications in other thread than get entity from database again, update entity state and save